# Cannot access database using different user from command line client

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in MySQL and I have only recently started using this server.  I have not used any other server prior. I am also a beginner in the SQL query language. 
When I downloaded the MySQL server, a program called the “MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client” was downloaded along with the “MySQL Shell”. I have been so far using the Command Line Client from the root user to access the database and write queries. I later decided to create a new user, from the command line client, by using this code:

```
> use mysql;
> CREATE USER 'LRNGSQL'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'lrngsql123';
> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'LRNGSQL'@'localhost';
> flush privileges;
```

I had to use ‘mysql’ database, which is a default database already there in the MySQL server, before I was able to create a new user. After I created a new user, I exited from my Command Line Client. When I start the Command Line Client, it directly asks for a password, I don’t need to specify the code:

```
Shell > mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

[This is how the Command Line Client terminal looks like when I start it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM0yC.jpg)

I get  a warning on the top before it asks me for the password. This is the warning:

> mysql: [Warning] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   8.0\bin\mysql.exe: ignoring option '--no-beep' due to invalid value ''

I don’t know what the warning on the top means, but I am able to access the database from the root user after I enter the password, so I just ignored it.

The Command Line Client allows me continue (i.e it gives me the 'mysql>' script) only if I enter the password for the root user, otherwise the program exits and closes. I tried typing in the password for the ‘LRNGSQL’ user, but I am not able to access the database using this password. Only the usage of the root password lets me access the database. I have tried accessing the database using the ‘LRNGSQL’ user from the Windows Command Prompt, and I have been successful with that. I cannot understand why I cannot do the same using the MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client. I would like to access the database from my other user.

Comment: try to use —no-default parameter on client start

Comment: rgen3 :It didn't work. There was this option called the "Use Legacy Console", I selected this, closed the Client, and restarted it. This also didn't work.

Comment: Please check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) for the available options, try this call: `mysql --user=LRNGSQL --password `

Comment: krokodilko: no that doesn't work either. After I type the password for the root user(because that is all it's taking), I am not able to type anything else except for queries, i.e. statements that end in ' ; ' .

Answer (score 0):

Download Sqlyog will solve all your problems. There you can create users easily.

https://www.webyog.com/

Comment: Yes, I do know of this. I want to understand why I am not able to access user from the Command Line Client. I should be able to, but I am not.